# C: Error at accessing dynamically allocated elements

Tags: c

I am trying to write a function that searches a certain element. However, it exists with error when I try to access an element. I commented the rows that generate the error in `search` function.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define m 2

typedef struct pag {
    int nr;
    int key[m];
    struct pag * child[m + 1];
}* page;

page init(page B) {
    int i;
    B = malloc(sizeof(struct pag));

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        B->key[i] = 0;
        B->child[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct pag));
    }
    B->child[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct pag));
    return B;
}

page search(page B, int k) {
    int i;
    if (B == NULL )
        return B;
    // 1. cautare liniara
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            // 2. find the desired value
        if (B->key[i] == k) {
            return B;
            // 3. find the value greater or equal, take the left road to the child
        } else if (B->key[i] >= k) {
            return search(B->child[i], k); //exists with error here
        }
    }

    return search(B->child[i], k); //also exists with error here
}

int main() {
    page B = init(B);

    if (search(B, 2) == NULL )
        printf("Negasit");
    else
        printf("Gasit");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean "exits with error" if so, what is the exact error?

Comment: @DanF my best guess is that it accesses an element from `B->child` that is not allocated.

Comment: This line: `page B = init(B);` seems odd.

Comment: @jedwards I'm willing to bet that is the root of the problem

Comment: @jedwards: It is odd because function parameter is completely redundant. But there's no problem with it.

Answer (score 2):

Your `init` function builds a two-level tree consisting of an initialized root node and a bunch (3 actually) of completely uninitialized child nodes. All your child nodes contain garbage.

When you do `search(B, 2)`, it will look through the root node and then recursively call `search` for one of the uninitialized child nodes (for the last one, actually). Since the child node is uninitialized, the code will either crash or do something else completely unpredictable.

Initialize your tree properly before trying to search anything in it.

Comment: since it checks for `NULL`, shouldn't that be avoided?

Comment: @Andrew: What `NULL` are you talking about? All your child nodes are allocates by `malloc`. `malloc` allocates memory block filled with unpredictable garbage. The code does not initialize allocated child memory in any way. There are no `NULL`s in your child nodes, only random garbage.

Comment: even if I don't `malloc` them I get the same result

Comment: @Andrew: I don't know what "don't malloc" is supposed to mean here. If you "don't malloc" your child nodes, they how are you creating them?

Comment: they will be created when they will be used.

Comment: @Andrew: Well, that must be some completely different code. We are not telepathic here. No one knows what happens in that version of your code.